# Freeze location of first line in beamer presentations

Tags: beamer, positioning

I always use the t option in my presentations:
`\documentclass[t]{beamer}`
If a try to press to much into one frame I have observed that the first line "jumps" one mm or so up and the text is compressed. Is there any way to avoid the jump by freezeing the location of the first line and then let LaTeX compress below the first line?
Example:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Hello}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Hello}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Hello}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item Is it me you're looking for?
  \item is it me you're looking for?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This code produces a small jump in the first line on the third slide.

Edit v1:
I was able to make a text line and itemize start on the same location by using:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{frame}[t]\frametitle{Hello}
\begin{itemize}[topsep = 0pt, partopsep = 0pt]
\item Is it me you`re looking for?
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Tried to use:

```
\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\partopsep}{0pt}
```

with normal itemize, but it did not work. Wonder why?

Edit v2:
Finally made it work without importing a package. This line in starts the itemize and normal text on the same locations:
    \mbox{}\vspace{-\topsep}\vspace{-\partopsep}\vspace{-\parsep}%

Example:

```
\begin{frame}
Yo banana boy
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\mbox{}\vspace{-\topsep}\vspace{-\partopsep}\vspace{-\parsep}%
\begin{itemize}
\item First item should line up with first line on previous page
\item $\cdots$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First item does not line up with first line on previous page
\item $\cdots$
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: One idea is to let beamer break frames with the `allowframebreaks` option given to the `frame` environment.

Comment: The `allowframebreaks` option works if I overfill the frame by alot. I guess the best solution is to not overfill the frame, but what I really want is absolute control over the position of the first line.

Comment: `itemize` adds some vertical space before and after. And obviously it is a shrinkable space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with BEAMER.

Some LaTeX environments like `itemize` add vertical spaces before and after the environment. In most cases they are stretchable and shrinkable, for flexibility.

To come over this, you may either

- control the spaces environment by environment.
- add a `\vss` at the of frames. It is an *infinitely* shrinkable space so it will disable other shrinkable spaces.

Comment: Thanks! Been searching for the solution all over the place. Did not know it was `itemize`.